# Plot data from MySQL with ChartJS

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I am building a sample application which retrieves data from sensors and plots it on a web page. What i am trying to do plot the data based on the user input but so far i am not able to get it done.

What i would like to achieve as an end result is the following:

The user will be presented with a dropdown menu to choose from all available devices and their respective parameters. Those parameters might be barometric pressure, temperature, humidity and so on. Based on that, a chart should be presented to the user when he or she submits the chosen variables.

What I have done so far is calling the mysql server and retrieve the data via API and plot it just for a single device and a single value without any user interaction functionality.

Here is how i statically retrieve the data:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $.ajax({
            url : "http://192.168.31.225/lora/api/get_data1.php",
            type : "GET",
            success : function(data){
                console.log(data);


          var Time = [];
          var temp = [];

          for(var i in data) {
            Time.push("" + data[i].time);
            temp.push(data[i].temp);
          }

          var chartdata = {
            labels: Time,
            datasets: [
              {
                label: "Temperature",
                fill: false,
                lineTension: 0.1,
                backgroundColor: "rgba(59, 89, 152, 0.75)",
                borderColor: "rgba(59, 89, 152, 1)",
                pointHoverBackgroundColor: "rgba(59, 89, 152, 1)",
                pointHoverBorderColor: "rgba(59, 89, 152, 1)",
                data: temp
              }          
            ]
          };

          var ctx = $("#mycanvas");

          var LineGraph = new Chart(ctx, {
            type: 'line',
            data: chartdata
          });
        },
        error : function(data) {
            console.log(data);
        }
      });
       });
```

The get_data1.php gets called which retrieves all of the available data from a single device. Here is the structure of the get_data1.php file

```
<?php
require_once(dirname(dirname(__FILE__)) . '/settings/mysqlhandler.php');

header('Content-Type: application/json');

$query = sprintf("SELECT * from Temperature");

$result = $con->query($query);

$data = array();
    foreach ($result as $row) {
        $data[] = $row;
}

$result->close();

$con->close();

print json_encode($data);
?>
```

Could you provide any pointers on how should I proceed?

Comment: Please describe the problem you're running into.

Comment: What I want to do is to retrieve dynamically the data from MySQL based on the user input. So far i am doing that statically.